# .NET - Every individual part of this script works, but running it as a whole causes it to replace all the text in my SVG file

Tags: .net, svg, replace, tags, powershell-4.0

I have created a script to automate Email Signature image creation.

The steps I'm trying to achieve are:

1. Replace the tagged text in the SVG file with a user's information.
2. Produce a PNG version of that SVG file using Inkscape CLI.
3. Replace the prior user's information in the SVG file with the next user's information, then repeat step 2.
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3 until all users have PNG Email Signature files.
5. Replace the last user's information in the SVG file with the original tags.

The Goals of the Script:

1. Allow new tags to be added to the SVG dynamically without having to change the script.
2. Accept input for the contacts and SVG template to be used.
3. List item

Here is my script:

```
param(
  [string]$targetDirectory=$(Convert-Path .),
  [string]$width = 980,
  [string]$height = 242,
  [string]$PNGname = "$Name - Signature.png"
  )
Write-Host ""

$scriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$CSVPrompt = 'Input the name of the CSV file you wish to use. Remember the file extension. It must be .txt or .csv and the file must be located in the same directory as this script.'
$SVGPrompt = 'Input the name of the SVG file you wish to use. Remember the file extension. It must be located in the same directory as this script.'
$targetCSV = Read-Host -Prompt $CSVPrompt
$targetSVG = Read-Host -Prompt $SVGPrompt
$contactList = import-csv $scriptPath\$targetCSV
$tags = $contactList[0] | Get-Member -Membertype 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'

Foreach ($tag in $tags) {New-Variable -Name "$tag" -Value "[$tag]";
  New-Variable -Name "prior$tag" -Value "[$tag]";}

function ReplaceInformation
  { # Gets the contents of the target SVG file; replaces the tag with the value; Sets the content of the file.
    (Get-Content $scriptPath\signature-template.svg).replace
      (
        (Get-Variable -Name "prior$tag" -ValueOnly),
        (Get-Variable -Name $tag -ValueOnly)
      ) | Set-Content $scriptPath\signature-template.svg;
  }

function ProducePNG
  { # Simple command to use Inkscape to convert SVG to PNG of a specified size.
    & "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" $targetSVG -z -e $PNGname -w $width -h $height;
  }

function ResetInformation
  { # This takes the last user's information and resets the tags back to their generic [<tag>].
    (Get-Content $scriptPath\signature-template.svg).replace((Get-Variable -Name "prior$tag" -ValueOnly), "[$tag]") | Set-Content $scriptPath\signature-template.svg;
  }

Foreach ($contact in $contactList)
  {
    Foreach ($tag in $tags)
      { # This produces variables set to the tag value in the contact. i.e. the $Name variable with the value of $contact.Name
        Set-Variable -Name "$tag" -Value $contact.$tag;
        ReplaceInformation
        Set-Variable -Name "prior$tag" -Value $contact.$tag;
      } # The "prior" variables are for chaining replace after the initial replacement. i.e. going from [Name] to Bob to Julie without having to reset back to [Name] until the last user is done.
    ProducePNG
  }
ResetInformation
```

Every individual function works fine when I run it in Powershell manually for its intended purpose. When I run the whole script, I see a lot of this but research isn't telling me what it means:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)

string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)

string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)

... etc etc for 100's of lines before the script completes.
```

I'm getting that when I only have 2 contacts in the input CSV and 4 tagged fields, so I would expect to see those line repeated, at most, 12-14 times for that many users. 100's of times doesn't make sense to me unless it's one per character.

The SVG file I have is 250KB in size, but when I run the script, I end up with nothing but the last tag in the list and the last user's value for that tag. So the 250KB SVG becomes nothing but this:

```
Receptionist
[Title]
```

Here's an example list of tags as they would be in the SVG file, but as stored in the `$tags` variable in Powershell. It alphabetizes but I don't think that's my issue. This just ends up being the order it does replacements in for each contact:

```
[Email]
[Name]
[Number]
[Title]
```

An example CSV comparable to what I'm using in testing:

```
Name,Email,Title,Number
Bob Saggett,bob@company.com,Janitor,9878
Julie Grey,julie2@company.com,Receptionist,9001
```

I feel like my problem's heart is in how I'm using the .NET Replace method, but from the documentation, I think I'm using it right.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

.NET version is 4.5.1 & PowerShell version is 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell script you should not carry call parameters to new line like this:

```
(Get-Content $scriptPath\signature-template.svg).replace
  (
    (Get-Variable -Name "prior$tag" -ValueOnly),
    (Get-Variable -Name $tag -ValueOnly)
  ) | Set-Content $scriptPath\signature-template.svg;
```

Above code causes `replace` to be actually executed without parameters. As result Powershell just prints possible overload defitions for `replace`. You could repeat this behavior if you type `"".replace` in Powershell window:

```
PS C:> "".replace

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)
```

So to fix the problem, change that `replace` call so that passed arguments are on the same line:

```
(Get-Content $scriptPath\signature-template.svg).replace((Get-Variable -Name "prior$tag" -ValueOnly), (Get-Variable -Name $tag -ValueOnly)) | Set-Content $scriptPath\signature-template.svg;
```

Regarding this:

> I'm getting that when I only have 2 contacts in the input CSV and 4
>   tagged fields, so I would expect to see those line repeated, at most,
>   12-14 times for that many users. 100's of times doesn't make sense to
>   me unless it's one per character.

There is a simple explanation why you observe so many incorrect calls to `replace`. `Get-Content` returns file content not as a single string, but as a collection of file lines. That's why `replace` is called as many times as many lines are contained in the `signature-template.svg` file.